# how to fix overlapping buttons in Android Studio Basic Map app using Framelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get my button layout to stop over lapping. Currently I'm using android studio Basic map running on a tablet with 4.2. Now the two buttons drop pin and draw line buttons from overlapping on the bottom of the screen. I know there is a buttonGroup() function or button layout, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:text="Drop new pin!"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:text="Draw Line" />

 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use other type of Layout like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout o something like that? When you use a FrameLayout frecuently it will overlap.

Hope it help you